# Moving from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a button within my view controller which i need to, once clicked, send the user to the next view controller, but it isn't working. I have ctrl dragged from my button to the controller that i want and the connection is made as a UIButton with touchUpInside selected. I have also named the segue but still nothing. The button itself isn't even recognising a touch has been made and isn't sending me anywhere. here is some code below from my main view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    JDTHMainMenu *theMenu = [[JDTHMainMenu alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:theMenu];

}

- (IBAction)matchViewControllerButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *matchScreenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [matchScreenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToMatchView:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [matchScreenButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    NSLog(@"Open Match View");


}
- (void)goToMatchView:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMatchView"]) {
        JDTHMatchScreen *vc2 = (JDTHMatchScreen *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.name = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

I have embedded this view controller in a navcontroller and that is the root controller. I read somewhere that maybe i needed to add something to my appdelegate but nothing was clear. I will post any more code deemed important, again i'm still at the early stages of learning so i'm not sure of which things are relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are not pushing/presenting a view controller, you are only assigning a value to v2.name.

You must fire the segue to push/present the second view controller from your button:

```
- (void)goToMatchViewController
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
}
```

This code could be use in `prepareForSegue:` to assign var' values to the 2nd VC. check the doc to see more.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMatchView"]) {
        JDTHMatchScreen *vc2 = (JDTHMatchScreen *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.name = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

[prepareForSegue, apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a)

Comment: I think you're right about this, but for some reason my button is not responding at all, i've tried adding NSLogs to check, reconnecting the button, creating another, bringing it to the front of the subview (due to imageview, and turning of user interactions on said imageview), and simplifying it just to get it to click and send an NSLog. Yet nothing works, any tips to find out why its not even recognising touch?

Comment: check your segue identify string, make sure it's the right one

Comment: sorry I didn't saw the `setUserInteractionEnabled` btw where is added your button ?

Comment: On the storyboard it is added underneath UIView (called Main Menu) on the JDTHViewController (first controller) i cant place it anywhere else without it disappearing. Originally i had all of this info in the UIView Main Menu but I couldnt get it to show up in the storyboard. So to clarify: My main ViewController has a UIview, i'm trying to add this button through the storyboard, and the code is in the main ViewControllers .m file.